# InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' && AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: this.Courses$.push is not a function

Tags: angular

I am having a problem since last night about this angular code as I am new to angular. 
The problem is, I am trying to push a new value into firebase and I am running into two problems intermediately.The Async pipe problem and the .push not a function error.
My codes are as follows:

**app.component.html**

```
   <input type="text" (keyup.enter)="add(course)" #course >

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor ="let cour of Courses$ | async">{{cour}}</li>
    </ul>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
 import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
 import {FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


 @Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
 export class AppComponent  {

 Courses$: FireListObservable<any>;

  constructor (db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.Courses$ = db.list('/Courses').valueChanges();

  }

  add(course: HTMLInputElement) {
   this.Courses$.push(course.value);
   course.value = '';
  }
 }
```

Now anytime i set Course$: FireListObservable, i get an error on this line of my code (bolded):

**this.Courses$** = db.list('/Courses');;

Also, when i change the type to Course$: AngularFireList, the error goes away but I get an **InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe** on my browser (console). Then when i set Course$ to Observable, I get error: **this.Courses$.push is not a function** . Please what can I do to correct this error. I will be very grateful. Thanks so much

Comment: `this.Courses$` is actually an object, not an array, so trying to do `this.Courses$.push` won't do anything, as `push` is a function specific to arrays. Can you show what `console.log(this.Courses$)` yields? It's likely that the array of information you want is actually buried in there!

Comment: thanks for the reply, I get an invalidPipeArgument: [Object Object] error. its just confusing to me. But I noticed firebase updates even with this error coming up on console, but this error prevents the list of courses from appearing on browser

Comment: Thanks guys  I was able to resolve it following this documentation here -> https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1180